# How to use multiple conditions in single DASL filter query in C#? (Syntax) (for advancedSearch() method)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, add-in

screenshot 1:
[image: screenshot 1]

screenshot 2:
[image: screenshot 2]

**BACKGROUND:**

Currently I am searching for a word in the subject of email in VSTO add-in. My syntax is:

```
string filter = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%" + wordInSubject + "%\'";
```

even the following syntax works:

```
string filter = String.Format("\"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject\" >= '{0}'", "ticket");

string filter = String.Format("@SQL=(\"urn:schemas:calendar:dtstart\" >= '{0:g}' " + "AND \"urn:schemas:calendar:dtend\" <= '{1:g}' " + "AND \"urn:schemas:mailheader:subject\" LIKE '%{2}%')", startTime, endTime, wordInSubject);
```

However, I also want to include DateTime comparison where the mail is between a time range.

**REASEARCH LINKS:**

[doc for multiple conditions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/andrewdelin/2005/08/08/outlook-sql-dasl-syntax-an-update/)

[doc with VB syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering-items-using-a-string-comparison)

***I tried following ways, however they don't work:***

```
string filter = ("urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%" + wordInSubject + "%\'") + ("[Start] >= '" + startTime.ToString("g") + "' + [End] <= '" + endTime.ToString("g") + "'"); 

string filter = ("urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%" + wordInSubject + "%\'") AND ("[Start] >= '" + startTime.ToString("g") + "' AND [End] <= '" + endTime.ToString("g") + "'");
```

***Also, while searching I read that it should be prefixed with "@SQL=" - however, even that condition throws error:-***

```
string filter = "@SQL=""urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%" + wordInSubject + "%\'"
```

**PROBLEM STATEMENT:-**

I am not looking for specifically DateTime case. But, I can work with just the syntax of using more than one condition in single filter string (any type of condition).

[link to advancedSearch() Method documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query that uses DASL property names:

```
@SQL=("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" LIKE '%test%') AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040" > '2017-09-25 00:00:00') AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040" < '2018-09-25 00:00:00')
```

It uses restriction on `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT_W` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F`) and `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040`).

DASL property names can be retrieved in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, select the property, see the DASL text box.

Comment: thanks for helping. But I am still getting syntax errors. I have updated the question with screenshots to give you a better understanding.

Comment: i tried this:
string filter = @"@SQL=(""http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040"" >= '" + (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)) + @"')"; and yet it doesnot work for me. any suggestions? @Dmitry Streblechenko

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52905750/errorcode-2147023281-message-the-operation-failed-in-c-sharp-using-advance
@Dmitry Streblechenko

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query that uses DASL property names:

```
@SQL=("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F" LIKE '%test%') AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040" > '2017-09-25 00:00:00') AND ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040" < '2018-09-25 00:00:00')
```

It uses restriction on `PR_NORMALIZED_SUBJECT_W` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E1D001F`) and `PR_MESSAGE_DELIVERY_TIME` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040`).

DASL property names can be retrieved in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author) - click IMessage button, select the property, see the DASL text box.