# ErrorCode: -2147023281, Message: "The Operation Failed" in C# using advancedSearch()

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, vsto, outlook-addin

**Background:**

I am using [advancedSearch()](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2012/05/31/outlook-search-csharp-vbnet/) for filtering my mailbox.

I was using filter as mentioned  in the above link as:

```
string filterValue = "ticket";

string filter = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE \'%" + filterValue + "%\'";
```

However, when I try the following:

```
DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2018, 9, 23, 16, 48, 0);

string filter = @"@SQL=(""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" >= '" + startTime.ToString("g") + @"')";`
```

This throws an exception saying, "This operation failed". Error Code:-2147023281

[image: screenshot]

**what else i have tried (but all of these throw exception and doesnot work):-**

```
        Outlook.PropertyAccessor pa = folder.PropertyAccessor;
        DateTime datStartUTC = pa.LocalTimeToUTC(Convert.ToDateTime("10/19/2018"));
        DateTime datEndUTC = pa.LocalTimeToUTC(Convert.ToDateTime("10/26/2018").AddDays(1));
        DateTime startTime = new DateTime(2018, 9, 23, 16, 48, 0);
        DateTime endTime = new DateTime(2018, 9, 26, 12, 00, 0);

        string filter = @"@SQL=((""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" + datStartUTC + @"' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <='" + datEndUTC + @"' ))";
        string filter = @"@SQL =((""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" >= '" + datStartUTC + @"' AND ""urn:schemas:httpmail:date"" <='" + datEndUTC + @"' ))";         
        string filter = ("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x0E060040 >  /' startTime /' ");
        string filter = "[Start] >= '" + startTime.ToString("g") + "' AND [End] <= '" + endTime.ToString("g") + "'";
        string filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived LIKE \'%" + pa.LocalTimeToUTC(DateTime.Now).ToString("g") + "%\'";
        string filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived LIKE \'%" + pa.LocalTimeToUTC(DateTime.Now) + "%\'";
        string filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived LIKE \'%" + (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)).ToString("g") + "%\'";
        string filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" <= '" + (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)).ToString("g") + @"');
        string filter = "urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived LIKE \'%" + startTime + "%\'";
        string filter = @"@SQL=(""urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived"" >= '" + (DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(7, 0, 0, 0)) + @"')";
```

exception message is either:

> the operation failed
>
> or
>
> something went wrong, please try again

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I discovered [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/search-and-filter/filtering) link in Microsoft Docs. In my case, the issue was a folder with a single quote, which was not being properly escaped. Since that folder was being used in the Scope property of the AdvacedSearch method, it was throwing the exception. Maybe it should help you to encounter what is missing in your code.